Redirect console to ttyUSB0
I'm trying to redirect the console to ttyUSB0, with the idea of later disable tty1, but I'm not getting anywhere....
I've added
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 console=ttyUSB0,19200n8r"

To /etc/default/grub and ran update-grub, confirms it work from looking at /proc/cmdline. But nothing appears on the console, and /proc/consoles only includes:
tty1                 -WU (EC p  )    4:1

Note that if I'm able to run agetty -t10 -8  -h ttyUSB0 19200 and it works fine, I can log in from the other end (with GTKTerm).
I've also added to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules (and ran update-initramfs -u)
usbserial
ftdi_sio

Thinking that the USB device is loaded too late, but that made no difference.
Any idea? Anybody managed to get this working?
Thanks.

The kernel is weird about printfs and USB comes late in the process maybe it's just not available when the kernel goes to bind to it so it never tries again later?

If it were not available, why would the be an explicit option for console=ttyUSB0 in the kernel?
I wonder if something is needed to be done to make it available ahead of time, hence my adding usbserial in initramfs.

Have Debian changed the "Debian currently does not build its Linux kernel with CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y, which is required for this feature to work." ?

As pointed out on reddit in this comment and by MatsK in the comment above, the drivers need to be compiled in the kernel for this to work, as the modules are loaded too late.
For serial console, there is a way to make it work with recompiling, and starts working only once the module is loaded, by using the <DEVNAME>:<n>.<n>[,options] syntax, but I thin that's for serial only and was not able to make it work with USB.
